# Unstable displaying of small pixel values

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with small values of pixels in CSS. When i need 1..2..3px (in other words small) values of border, margin etc. Browser behavior is unstable and i can see sometimes elements which have the same parameters in CSS that look different.

For example, i have added `:before` pseudoelements to show two vertical gray lines and that is initial CSS:

```
 &:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 2px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: $color_white;
            opacity: .6;
            mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
          }
```

So in my last Chrome it looks that:

[image]

As you can see vertical borders have not the same width of 2px. Moreover when i zoom it the width of left vertical border can look more that rigth and on the contrary.

**But** i solved it by setting width to 1.5px `width: 1.5px` and now it looks great also when i zooming:[image]

What is going on? Why do i see elements bad when 1-2-3px integer values and changing it to fractional (sometimes to 1.7px 1.8px and so on) solves the problem? How to fix that nice way?

Comment: Because that's how browser is displaying it. Can you provide working example here is SO Snippet?